# How to take 0 decimal place "double" data type and output corresponding number of "*" automatically

Tags: c#

I have written my first c# file. Basically what I have is someone puts in different ratings out of 10 (as doubles) for a product for things like taste, texture, presentation etc. I created a weighing system and rating the overall review automatically out of 10.
I used `Math.Round` to round it up to the closest whole number.

I want to display the following line as the following output:

> "Overall rating is  5/10 : *****"

Where the number of "*" displayed is automatically displayed as the overall rating calculated (as a whole number).

I have no idea how to do this final bit.

My final output line so far is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Overall rating is " + ratingRounded + "/10: ");
```

How would I display the "*" to equally be the same as `ratingRounded`?

Sorry, I likely did a very bad job explaining it all (I tried my best!).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This one's pretty short...

```
string stars = new String('*', (int)ratingRounded);
Console.WriteLine("Overall rating is " + ratingRounded + "/10: "+stars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop.

```
Console.Write("Overall rating is " + ratingRounded + "/10: ");
for(int i=0; i<ratingRounded; i++){
    Console.Write("*");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect. I never thought of writing in a for loop like that. So simple. I also tried "Enumerable.Repeat". Your way is awesome!

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer if it worked for you? :)

Comment: @TajkiaRahmanToma Not until [15 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use (if ratingRounded is numeric datatype and not string)

```
Console.WriteLine("Overall rating is " + ratingRounded + "/10: " + new String('*', ratingRounded));
```